# How can I feel feedback with electric power steering (EPS)?

Tags: sensors, actuator, steering, can

When I am rotating steering wheel and it meets an obstacle, I feel it. I have EPS. How does it work? Is it just explicit sensor and feedback? Can I sniff this feedback on CAN bus?

Comment: `Can I sniff this feedback on CAN bus?` ... surely the answer depends on the manufacturer ... please be aware of what information you provided and what questions you are asking about that information ... actually, all of your questions are manufacturer dependent

Comment: Please provide few most poplar cases from different manufacturers.

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... it is not "do research for me" forum ... please do the research and ask question here about anything that you do not understand

Comment: your simplest course of action may be to ask at an automobile related site

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment to write up a full answer, but I think what you're looking for is "force feedback." I don't know for sure how force-feedback devices actually work, but my guess would be some form of compliant control.